# Splunk Web only monitoring files from /var/log directory of forwarder

Tags: splunk

My splunk web only monitoring files from /var/log directory of forwarder and when I am trying to add other files from different directory using add monitor command it is not appearing on Splunk web. Please help!

Comment: That's not much to work with.  What is your exact splunk monitor command you entered?  Can you share the contents of $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/inputs.conf?  What is the query you use to display the data in Splunk?

Comment: I have entered both ./splunk add monitor /opt/workload1 . and ./splunk add monitor /opt/var/log but splunk web is monitoring only files under /var/log dircetory. I can't find data from workload directory.

Comment: But forwarder is showing that it is monitoring files from workload1 directory also but can't find any details on splunk web for same. I am searching data with host name of forwarder on splunk web.

Comment: inputs.conf file contain  host = xxx.com (Forwarder host name )

[monitor://opt/workload1/]
_TCP_ROUTING = *
index = TEST

Comment: So it appears to be monitoring /opt/workload1.  Does the TEST index exist?  Indexes must be created before they are used.  Try this search: `index=* host=xxx.com`.

Comment: I have searched with above parameter but I am getting results only from /var/log directory. That /opt/workload1/ directory that I have mentioned in inputs.conf dfileis not appearing in Splunk web

Comment: Does Splunk have read access to /opt/workload1?

Comment: No, it was not...I have given that and now files from workload1 are accessible for splunk...thanks a lot for your timely help.

Comment: Happy to help.  I created an answer for you to accept so others might benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify Splunk has read access to /opt/workload1.